# assign variable arguments in FREDR syntax

Tags: r

I would like to assign the following arguments in the syntax FREDR and use map_dfr to download two data frames at once.
Here is what I normally do

```
fredr(series_id = "SP500",
             observation_start = as.Date("2002-01-01"),
             observation_end = as.Date("2020-12-01"),
             frequency = "m",
             units = "pch")
```

This is what I want to do by adding "units" and "frequency" arguments. It won't work

```
map_dfr(c("PCEC96", "SP500"),fredr(units="pch",frequency="m"))
```

Is there a way to get around with it?

Thank you

Comment: In the `map` o you need to subset by dates - i.e.`observation_start` and `observation_end`

Answer (score 1):

We can specify the anonymous function as either `function(x)` or use the shorthand `~` and specify as `.x`

```
 library(purrr)
out1 <- map_dfr(c("PCEC96", "SP500"), ~ fredr(.x, units= "pch",frequency= "m"))
```

Or we can just specify the arguments without the `()`

```
out2 <- map_dfr(c("PCEC96", "SP500"), fredr, units= "pch", frequency= "m")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `lapply` :

```
cols <- c("PCEC96", "SP500")
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(cols, function(x) fredr(x, units="pch",frequency="m")))
```